# Error page registrar and Global exception handling

Tags: spring-boot, exception, custom-error-pages

I am creating a Spring Boot web application, but i am confused why people use Global Exception handlers(@ControllerAdvice) when there is Error Page Registrar which is neater and more explicit. Please can someone explain more and is it possible to call an Error page registrar from a global Exception Handler Class( class annoted with @ControllerAdvice, with an @Exceptionhandler method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Brian answer, I think you can do this. I got a sample to prove this one in here if you still need to refer:  https://github.com/kennytai/SampleSpringbootExceptionHandler 
At this sample, I use the `@ControllerAdvice` in class `GlobalExceptionHandler` to manage all exceptions from `TestController`.

Hope this help.

Comment: it is very helpful...i am still going over it, but my question is since both are useful in thier own way, can i call a ExceptionPageRegistrar from a GlobalExceptionHandler

Comment: I think it's possible. You can throw any Exception and GlobalExceptionHandler just gets that one and handles the message, response code...etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the opposite the [error pages mechanism in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-error-handling) is the global one; it's catching all exceptions unhandled by the application. Note that in a Servlet environment, it's even dispatching the request back into the container on the `/error` path.

You're right though, this mechanism is really powerful and you can achieve a lot with it.

The other exception handling mechanisms you're mentioning are provided by Spring MVC itself. They're executed during the handling of the request and don't require an additional dispatch to the container. In some cases, they can be more limited because they offer less features than the full `ErrorController` (which is an MVC Controller).
But unlike error pages, you can configure those to focus on only specific errors:

- You can declare an `@ExceptionHandler` within a Controller and specify the type of Exception you'd like to handle
- You can configure the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to only apply to specific packages, Controllers extending a specific interface or annotated with a specific annotation

I'd say the latter are quite useful when you want to deal with business exceptions at the controller level. You can do that with error pages, but you might end up with a single error controller dealing with too many things.

Comment: Thanks alot. My question is since both are useful in thier own way, can i call a ExceptionPageRegistrar from a GlobalExceptionHandler