# Does ControllerAdvice increase response time?

Tags: spring, exception, model-view-controller

Is there any speed difference when using ControllerAdvice throwing RuntimeException, and when manually returning ResponseEntity to handle client errors?

1) ControllerAdvice

```
@RestController
public class ObjectController {
    @PostMapping
    public Object save(@RequestBody Object object) {
        if (service.isInvalid(object))
            throw new ObjectException("Client error");
        return service.save(object);
    }
}

public class ObjectException extends RuntimeException {

}

@ControllerAdvice
public class ObjectControllerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {ObjectException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(ObjectException ex,  WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), new HttpHeaders(), 
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }

}
```

2) Manually returning ResponseEntity

```
@RestController
public class ObjectController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> save(@RequestBody  Object object) {
        if (service.isInvalid(object))
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Client error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(service.save(object), HttpStatus.OK);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the difference is response time is negligible with the second approach possibly being very slightly faster. But the real advantage of having a @ControllerAdvice class with @ExceptionHandlers is that these can be used for multiple endpoints over multiple @Controllers and you won't have to repeat the code everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not that much different. And I think using the @ControllerAdvice is a best practice when you would like to handle your Custom Exception or to centralize the Exception to a Global class. There is a simple sample in this answer: [Error page registrar and Global exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881425/error-page-registrar-and-global-exception-handling/45886075#45886075)

Hope this help.